# Different Representation of a Direct Product

Tags: computational-mathematics, gap

Let us say I have two matrix groups G and H and dimensions of the matrices in those groups are $3\times3$. When I use the function DirectProduct(G,H), it creates a matrix group in which the dimensions of the matrices are $6\times6$. Basically, it calculates the direct sum of two matrices. However, what I want is the basic form of a direct product which is elements of type (g,h).

I tried the following code:

```
gap> gl_V2 := GL(3,5);
GL(3,5)
gap> gl_V3 := GL(3,5);
GL(3,5)
gap> Size(gl_V2);
1488000
gap> Size(gl_V3);
1488000
gap> last*last2;
2214144000000
gap> mydirectproduct:=function(G,H)
> local i,j,result;
> result:=[];
> for i in G do
>   for j in H do
>     Add(result, [i,j]);
>   od;
> od;
> return result;
> end;
```

which took forever to compute of course (actually I am not sure if it computed or not). Is there a way to do this efficiently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason GAP chooses a matrix group representation is that calculations in it will be significantly faster than when using formal pairs. What would a representation as pairs let you do, which the matrix group representation does not?

Comment: I am going to act on a tensor product space. One of the matrices should act from left and one should act from right. V $\otimes$W is my tensor product space and I want to act by GL(V)xGL(W) by the action I description above.

Comment: @ahulpke What happens if I just use the generators? Can I say generate the group with generators $[(e_1,f_1),...(e_n,f_m)]$ where $e_i$ 's are the generators of GL(V) and $f_i$'s are the generators of GL(W)?

Comment: If you use the `Projection` homomorphisms, you can map back to the constituent groups.

Comment: Esat Akin. To generate the direct product you need generators $(e_i,1)$ and $(1,f_j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DirectProduct` by design (as all other group products) chooses a representation in which calculations are efficient and only as a fall-back defaults to a formal pair representation. One can use `Embedding` and `Projection` to (de)compose elements.
One could use `ApplicableMethod` to get the fallback method for testing purposes, but I would not recommend doing so (and thus will not explain further how this could be done).

If -- say for an orbit algorithm -- you really need elements as pairs (to avoid a cost from `Projection`), I would simply construct generators of the direct product as `Tuple([a,b])` and form the group generated by them (without making a formal direct product object). Clearly you do not need to form all pairs, but it is sufficient to take pairs $(e,1)$ and $(1,f)$ with $e$ running through the generators of the first group and $f$ ditto for the second group.